# Updating /Delete rows from JQUERY Datatable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have `Jquery DataTable` in which add,delete and edit options are there.After adding a new row when i am trying to delete or edit that row it's getting affected in the `database`,but while coming to table it's not getting changed.While editing a new row is getting added on the `datatable` and while deleting it's not getting removed.But after reopening the application it's working fine.

Code:

This is my Datatable

```
var activityTablePat = $('.gridTablesummaryPat').DataTable({ "pageLength": 5, "bFilter": false, "bInfo": false, "bLengthChange": false });
```

this is the code iam using for updating and adding the rows.

```
var removeRow = $('.gridTablesummaryPat tr[data-id="' + data.ID + '"]');                    
activityTablePat.row(removeRow).remove().draw(); 
activityTablePat.row.add({ 0: '<input name="radio" data-startdate="' + data.StartDate + '" data-enddate="' + data.EndDate + '" data-custid="' + data.CustID + '" data-custname="' + data.CustomerName + '" data-patid="' + data.PatID + '" data-patname="' + data.PatientName + '"  data-contrname="' + data.ContractName + '" data-description="' + data.ContractDescription + '" value="' + data.ID + '" class="radiobuttonCust" type="radio" />', 1: data.CustomerName, 2: data.PatientName, 3: data.ActivityCount, 4: data.StartDate, 5: data.EndDate }).draw();
```

in the above code `removeRow` is the `rowIndex`. If i add a new row and immediately try to update  or delete that row ,the value of `removeRow` becomes `null`.

Is it because the row is not getting added to the `datatable` `gridTablesummaryPat`

Comment: I don't see where the data-id attribute is getting added in your insert row code. Maybe the since the new row doesn't have it the remove row function looks for a TR with a data-id attribute it finds nothing.

Comment: How to add the `data-id` attribute for the `tr` every time i insert a new row?

Comment: Assuming your data-id is the same as data.id... `'<input name="radio" data-id='"+ data.id +"'  data-startdate="' + data.StartDate + '" data-enddate="' + data.EndDate + '" data-custid="' + data.CustID + '" data-custname="' + data.CustomerName + '" data-patid="' + data.PatID + '" data-patname="' + data.PatientName + '"  data-contrname="' + data.ContractName + '" data-description="' + data.ContractDescription + '" value="' + data.ID + '" class="radiobuttonCust" type="radio" />', 1: data.CustomerName, 2: data.PatientName, 3: data.ActivityCount, 4: data.StartDate, 5: data.EndDate }).draw();`